Is the subspace $\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ inheriting the product topology normable?
We know that the product topology on $X := \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n = \prod_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{R}^n$ is not normable (that is, is induced by a norm), since if it was then  $X$ would be metrizable, but only a countable product of metrizable spaces can be metrizable.
If we take the set of linear transformations $\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and endow it with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so that its topology is made of sets which are are intersections between open sets of $X$ and the set $\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we get a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n^2$ that is also a topological subspace $Y \leq X $.
My question, is the space $Y$ normable? Is there any norm  $\| \cdot \| : \text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R} $ that induces the subspace topology of $Y$?

Every finite-dimensional Hausdorff TVS is normable. Indeed, it is a standard fact that an $n$-dimensional Hausdorff TVS is linearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb{K}^n$, where the latter is equipped with the Euclidean topology.
(More directly, you can just take the standard basis $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and check that, on $\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, pointwise convergence at those $n$ points is equivalent to pointwise convergence everywhere, so the topology on $Y$ can be generated by the norm $T \mapsto \sum_{i = 1}^n \|Te_i\|$.)

You mean convergence of nets, right?

@SassatelliGiulio You mean when I say the two kinds of pointwise convergence are equivalent? Yes, I meant convergence of nets.

If we let $\mathcal B = \{e_1,\ldots,e_n\} \subset \mathbb R^n$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$, there is a natural continuous projection map
$$\prod_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{R}^n \to \prod_{e_i \in \mathbb B} \mathbb R^n
$$
This projection map restricts to a continuous function $P : \text{End}(\mathbb R^n) \to \prod_{e_i \in \mathbb B} \mathbb R^n$. I'll show that this restricted function is a homeomorphism. To describe the inverse homeomorphism $P^{-1} : \prod_{e_i \in \mathbb B} \mathbb R^n \to \text{End}(\mathbb R^n)$, an element of the domain of $P^{-1}$ is a function of the form
$$e_1 \mapsto w_1\,\, , \,\, ... \,\, , \,\, e_n \mapsto w_n
$$
This function extends uniquely to an endomorphism of $\mathbb R^n$ by the formula
$$v = c_1 e_1 + \ldots + c_n e_n \mapsto c_1 w_1 + \cdots + c_n w_n
$$
Notice that for each fixed $v = c_1 e_1 + \ldots + c_n e_n$, the output $c_1 w_1 + \cdots + c_n e_n$ is clearly continuous as a function of the tuple $(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$. So this formula clearly implies continuity of $\Pi^{-1}$.
Finally, it should be clear that $\displaystyle \Pi_{e_i \in \mathcal B} \mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R^n)^n$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. In fact this is a familiar homeomorphism, because of the familiar identification of $\text{End}(\mathbb R^n)$ with the set of $n \times n$ matrices of real numbers.
